# A word problem on trigonometry

Tags: trigonometry, word-problem

> Justin is a very fluctuant employee. He sells the max of 200 dollars worth of product on day 3. He sells the min of 30 dollars worth of product on day 7. Let $t=0$ represent the day he started working this job. Write the equation that represents the sales amount as a function of time.

I got $ y=-85\cos((2\pi/7)x)+115$.

My reasoning is that $115-85=30$ (the min) and $115+85 = 200 $ (the max). Is my reasoning in the right direction?

Comment: The definition of *fluctuant* seems to be [fluctuating : unstable].  Therefore, it seems that the problem is ambiguous.  That is, you could presume that he sells the maximum on all days that are (for example) not congruent to $1 \pmod{3}$, and he sells the minimum on days that are congruent to $1 \pmod{3}.$  What is the background of the problem?  For example, is this from a book or class where a special definition has been given for the word *fluctuant*?  Alternatively, have there been worked examples in the book or class whose solution involved a trig function?

Comment: Part, but not all of the ambiguity could be resolved with the added constraint (that is so far unstated) that the sales amount as a function of time is represented by a continuous function.

Comment: bruh what... lmao

Comment: I do not understand your last comment.  The comment suggests that you wish me to explain my last comment: okay: One (**of many**) possible continuous functions would be that for $0 < t \leq 3$, $f(t)$ [**in this interval**] is **the** straight line function, where $f(1) = 30$ and $f(3) = 200$.  Similarly, for $3 \leq t \leq 7$ you could have that $f(t)$ [in this interval] is the straight line function where $f(3) = 200$ and $f(7) = 30$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I do believe your reasoning is looking in the correct direction. However, I can say that your equation is incorrect, because it reaches the max at day $3.5$ instead of day $3$. I would recommend next steps involving adjusting how you dilate and translate horizontally in order to fix this misalignment.